# supervisor laravel queue worker terminated by SIGKILL

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

On a production env, I use `supervisor` to run my queue worker as follow:

```
php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
```

I have a job running when a user registers setting up their environment (multi tenancy), meaning it creates their own database, sets up their default users, etc. This job can take a few minutes to run.

It works perfectly fine in dev, but gets killed all the time in production:

```
2021-11-23 09:30:44,654 INFO exited: larvel-worker_01 (terminated by SIGKILL; not expected)
```

In the worker's logs, I just see the job trying to be run again, up to 3 times, as expected. (failing because the database already exists and cannot be created again obviously).

The delay between worker start and kill changes, so I'm guessing this may have to do with resources, but the server is not busy at all (CPU, RAM, etc all less than 10% usage).

I'm using php 7.4 cli on a Debian, with the following configuration:

```
memory_limit => -1 => -1
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
```

Any idea what to look at ?

Comment: Do you have any system log records for the process SIGKILL? There is probably memory usage issue. Try to execute worker without supervisor, does it get SIGKILL?

Comment: No I don't. I'll look into this as I have no idea how this could work. I tried running without supervisor and it get killed as well:
```[2021-11-29 08:07:36][168] Processing: Stancl\JobPipeline\JobPipeline
Killed
```

Comment: How much RAM has the server? Try to exec with memory limited to reasonable value (available value - 10%) `php  -d memory_limit=512M artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600` This should help to get a clue where memory ends off. Probably memory leak

Comment: 8.37 GiB used / 62.88 GiB total at the moment. Tried with memory_limit=512M, the process gets killed as well.

Comment: What `dmesg` says after the process gets killed?

Comment: Here are a few logs I see:
`/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log`
`[...]-worker_05 (terminated by SIGKILL; not expected)`

`dmesg -T`
no entry for today (so nothing related to my process being killed)
It definitely looks like there is 90 seconds before the process gets killed, so I'm thinking about a timeout/max execution time, but cannot find out where

Comment: I am having same issue now. Did you find the solution?

Comment: No, this is still happening. We migrated to AWSCloud, but I'd be interested if you find anything